# CSS/HTML: Photo Gallery Thumbnails Smaller than Hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a photo gallery in HTML and adding space between the thumbnails with CSS.  The problem I'm running into is that when I go to click on the thumbnail image the "a" tag hyperlink hangs below, above or to the side of the image depending on the margins or padding.  How can I get rid of this and have the hyperlink stay within the confines of the thumbnail image only?

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="gallery">
      <a href="EastAsia/eastasia_photo1.html"><img src="../images/EastAsia/1.jpg" alt=" "></a>
      <a href="EastAsia/eastasia_photo1.html"><img src="../images/EastAsia/1.jpg" alt=" "></a>
      <a href="EastAsia/eastasia_photo1.html"><img src="../images/EastAsia/1.jpg" alt=" "></a>
      <a href="EastAsia/eastasia_photo1.html"><img src="../images/EastAsia/1.jpg" alt=" "></a>
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  width: 960px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Thanks everyone.  I ended up putting each image into a Div class and then set the margin on that class which eliminated the problem!

Comment: set your img to `display:block;` in stead of `inline-block`. (set up a fiddle if that does not do the trick)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the padding from `a`, and move the margin from the image to `a`.  Since the `a` wrapps the image, and the image has margin, the `a` is also wrapped in the margin. If you actually want the margin on the `a` block, so that clicking it does nothing:

```
.gallery a { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the styles to the a tag:

```
display:inline-block;
font-size:1px;
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/XRhWe/
The second object from the left.